# Android room one to many and compute values

Tags: android, sql, android-room, relation

I have a one to many relation in room.
I need to fetch list of data and calculate one property on every object as sum of amounts.
Can i write a query for that? or i must iterate over the values in the code?

Update

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "account_table")
class AccountModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    var name: String,
    var bankNumber: String,
    var amount: Double
)


@Entity(tableName = "spent_table")
data class SpentModel(
    var amount: Double,
    var title: String,
    var description: String,
    var date: String?,
    var accountId: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
)

data class AccountWithSpent(
    @Embedded val account: AccountModel,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "accountId"
    )
    val spent: List<SpentModel>
)
```

`AccountWithSpent` is one to many relation of my data and i want get all amounts from spent and store it to account object amount property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i write a query for that?

**Yes**

> or i must iterate over the values in the code?

**No, but you could.**

**Note** although perhaps useful content you may wish to go straight to the bottom and read the **Additional/Correction** section.

Assuming that you want to get the sum of the amounts spent when retrieving one or more **AccountWithSpent** objects, then you could include a val/field for this in **AccountWithSpent** e.g. :-

```
data class AccountWithSpent(
    @Embedded val account: AccountModel,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "accountId"
    )
    val spent: List<SpentModel>,
    val sumOfSpent: Double /*<<<<< ADDED for SUM*/
)
```

You could then have a query such as :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT *, (SELECT sum(spent_table.amount)  FROM spent_table WHERE spent_table.accountId = a.id) AS sumOfSpent   FROM account_table AS a")
    fun getAccountWithSpent(): List<AccountWithSpent>
```

- `AS sumOfSpent` is important, it names that column from which the data is to be obtained to be the same name of the field in the POJO, they MUST match.
- `AS a` disambiguates the **id** column when it is used in the WHERE clause of the subquery (`(SELECT sum(spent_table.amount)  FROM spent_table WHERE spent_table.accountId = a.id)`)

  - i.e. both the account_table and the spent_table have an **id** column. So using a.id enforces the use of the account_table id.

You could also have a query such as :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT account_table.*, sum(spent_table.amount) AS sumOfSpent FROM account_table JOIN spent_table ON account_table.id = spent_table.accountId GROUP BY account_table.id")
fun getAccountWithSpentV2(): List<AccountWithSpent>
```

- This doesn't use a subquery but instead JOIN's the tables and uses GROUP BY to group rows into accounts.
- To suppress the unused columns (from the spent_table), which Room issues a warning about, `account_table.*` is used to define the output columns (i.e. only columns from the account table)

  - again Room builds the underlying Spent objects from the accounts

**Alternative**

If you only wanted the Account with the Sum and not the List of the underlying Spent objects then you could use the following:-

```
data class AccountWithSumOfSpent(
    @Embedded
    val account: AccountModel,
    val sumOfSpent: Double
)
```

with :-

```
@Query("SELECT *, sum(spent_table.amount) AS sumOfSpent FROM account_table JOIN spent_table ON account_table.id = spent_table.accountId GROUP BY account_table.id")
fun getAccountWithSumofSpent(): List<AccountWithSumOfSpent>
```

- Note     `@Transaction` is not required as all data is extracted by the single query

  - the subquery is embedded in the main query. However, when using @Relation Room builds and executes queries in addition to the main query and hence why it warns about using `@Transaction`

**Working Example using both methods**

```
    /* ADD 1 Account with 3 Spends (totalling $100.00) */
    val account1Id = dao.insert(AccountModel(0,"BANKX","000000",0.00)).toInt()
    dao.insert(SpentModel(30.00,"SPEND1","BUYA","2021-06-25",account1Id))
    dao.insert(SpentModel(30.00,"SPEND2","BUYB","2021-06-24",account1Id))
    dao.insert(SpentModel(40.00,"SPEND3","BUYC","2021-06-23",account1Id))

    /* Extract and Log using first method (Account, with Sum and with all Spends) */
    for(a: AccountWithSpent in dao.getAccountWithSpent()) {
        Log.d("ACCNTINFO","Account Name is ${a.account.name} Bank Number is ${a.account.bankNumber} SUM of Spend is ${a.sumOfSpent}")
        //Log.d("ACCNTINFO","Account Name is ${a.account.name} Bank Number is ${a.account.bankNumber}")
        for(s: SpentModel in a.spent) {
            Log.d("ACCNTINFO","Title is \t${s.title} Description is ${s.description} Date is ${s.date} Amount is ${s.amount}")
        }
    }
    /* Extract and Log using second method (no Spends) */
    for(a: AccountWithSumOfSpent in dao.getAccountWithSumofSpent()) {
        Log.d("ACCNTINFO", "Account Name is ${a.account.name} Bank Number is ${a.account.bankNumber} SUM of Spend is ${a.sumOfSpent}")
    }
```

**Result**

The Log includes :-

```
2021-06-26 07:58:55.265 D/ACCNTINFO: Account Name is BANKX Bank Number is 000000 SUM of Spend is 100.0
2021-06-26 07:58:55.265 D/ACCNTINFO: Title is   SPEND1 Description is BUYA Date is 2021-06-25 Amount is 30.0
2021-06-26 07:58:55.265 D/ACCNTINFO: Title is   SPEND2 Description is BUYB Date is 2021-06-24 Amount is 30.0
2021-06-26 07:58:55.265 D/ACCNTINFO: Title is   SPEND3 Description is BUYC Date is 2021-06-23 Amount is 40.0


2021-06-26 07:58:55.268 D/ACCNTINFO: Account Name is BANKX Bank Number is 000000 SUM of Spend is 100.0
```

**Additional/Correction**

> I need to fetch list of data and calculate one property on every object as sum of amounts.
> AccountWithSpent is one to many relation of my data and i want get all amounts from spent and store it to account object amount property.

I didn't properly read the above, so based upon your **original AccountWithSpent** then you could use:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT account_table.id,account_table.name, account_table.bankNumber, sum(spent_table.amount) AS amount FROM account_table JOIN spent_table ON account_table.id = spent_table.accountId GROUP BY account_table.id")
fun getAccountWithSpent(): List<AccountWithSpent>
```

and the AccountModel's amount will be populated accordingly.

**However**, it should be noted that the amount in the database will still be what it was, it will not change. A rhetorical question, do you need the amount to be saved in the database as it can always be calculated?

Perhaps have AccountModel have:-

```
.....
@Ignore 
var amount: Double
```

If you want the amount in the database then perhaps you should ALWAYS maintain the amount in the database. If so then you may wish to consider using a TRIGGER(s) whenever a Spend is added/deleted or updated to adjust the amount automatically *(if so then that would have to be another question)*.